# Google Apps Scripts: How do I insert an element from an array into a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work in an inventory control company & need to sort Google Sheets data which I extract from client reports. Presently I manually sort the data following the same steps each time. I am trying to automate the process using Google Apps Script. In this example the spreadsheet data is an on hand inventory report. The report has 6 columns every time but varying rows of data. As per sample below.

```
+--------+---------------------------+-------------+------------+---------+--------------+
| Bin No |         Item Name         |   Station   | Item Size  | On-Hand | On-Hand(UOM) |
+--------+---------------------------+-------------+------------+---------+--------------+
|   8331 | 5 Seed Low Sugar          | First Level | 345 ml     |       8 | BOTTLE       |
|   8331 | 5 Seed Low Sugar          | First Level | 6 x 345 ml |       1 | CASE         |
|   7530 | Abel's Tempest Chardonnay | First Level | 750 ml     |       5 | BOTTLE       |
+--------+---------------------------+-------------+------------+---------+--------------+
```

I sort the entire data set by rows that have the text "CASE" in the 6th column (On-Hand(UOM)) into the "caseCounts" array & rows that do not into the "sglCounts" array . These are now my 2 arrays to use to get my final count file report.

I need to split out the "CASE" size from the 4th column(Item Size) in the "caseCounts" array. So I remove the 4th column, use it to create a new array called "caseSizeOnly" which holds all the case sizes. In the example above it is 6 & drop the "x 345 ml".

I need to then combine the "caseSizeOnly" array with the "caseCounts" array. This is where I have encountered difficulty.

My attempts so far:

```
// --------------------------------- Sort Counts  to CountFile sheet  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


function countFile() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActive();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("report");
  var onHand = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow(),6).getValues();

  var caseCounts = []; // This array contains only the items counted as CASEs
  var sglCounts = []; // This array contains all the other counts




  // Sorting the intiial data into Case counts & Single bottle counts
  onHand.map(function(r){
    var d = r[5]
    if(d.toString().indexOf("CASE") === -1){
     sglCounts.push(r);
    } else {
      caseCounts.push(r);
    }
  });


  var arr3 = removeEl(caseCounts, 3);// new array without column "Pack Size"

  var arr4 = caseCounts.map(splitCol); // returns ONLY the case size out of the "Pack Size" column which must be added back to arr3


// attemting to combine the 2 arrays & failing miserably! this is about the 100th version of my attempts
         for(var i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
          arr3.push(arr4[i]);
            }

      Logger.log(arr3);

     }

   /*                // --------------------------------- Adding case size to caseCount array NOT WORKING!!!!!!!!  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------




       */                 

                    // -------------------------------  Function to Split out column Pack Size ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

                        function splitCol(row){

                            var caseSize = row[3].split(" x");
                            var caseOnly = caseSize.slice(0,1);

                       //   Logger.log(caseOnly);

                           return caseOnly;

                        }


                   // -------------------------------  Function to remove column Pack Size ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

                        function removeEl(array, remIdx) {
                        return array.map(function(arr) {
                        return arr.filter(function(el,idx){return idx !== remIdx});  
                        });
                        };

                   // -------------------------------  END Function to remove column Pack Size ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet so I can extract the data from it?

Comment: Hi Cooper yeah I can: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pwzaWdhoeFlIUKwuBKiorozHWg_e92PzJyXLgISzz5s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly when `arr3` is created, it looks like this:

```
[[8331.0, 5 Seed Low Sugar, First Level, 1.0, CASE]]
```

And then you want to take the number of bottles in the case (in this example 6), and multiply it with the number of cases (in this example 1) to get the total number of bottles. Something like:

```
[[8331.0, 5 Seed Low Sugar, First Level, 6.0, CASE]]
```

If that is what you are after, you need to do this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
    arr3[i][3] *= arr4[i];
  }
```